# What is ...store in React Native Redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am learning on React Native Redux.
But I can't know what is ...store or ...state.
My code of Reducer is

```
...
const defaultState = {
...
};
export default (store = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case XXX: {
     return {
     ...store,
     XXX: XXX
    };
  ...
   }
  }
};
```

I need details about ...store.
I can't find via googling. Thank you.

Comment: I've had the same question in the past: it sure is a tough one to google for :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which basically *spreads* all the properties of one object out i.e. if:

```
let myObject = {
  foo: 'bar',
  value: 1
}
```

And you use:

```
let another = {
  ...myObject,
  thing: 2
}
```

You'll get:

```
another = {
  foo: 'bar',
  value: 1,
  thing: 2
}
```

In the case of Redux you're saying that you want to return the existing contents of the store, plus some other properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should defintely call your "store" parameter as "state" to avoid confusion.

You are writing a reducer, which takes the current state and an action and returns the new state.

The Redux store is the part of Redux which holds and manages your Redux state (allow access to state, dispatch actions through middleware and reducer, register listeners etc...).

I suggest that you read the "Basic" part of Redux documentation to understand the meaning of state, actions, reducers and store:
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/index.html

In your reducer you will user `...state` (the object/array spread operator) to create the new state starting from the current state.

See here for the use of the spread operator in your reducers:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html

I hope this helps, Matteo